# Retrieve a Report via sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm using sfdx to retrieve a report:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Report:PublicReports/reportname
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Report:Public\ Reports/reportname
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'Report:Public Reports/reportname'
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
```

I can see the report there when I do :

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q 'SELECT Id, Name, FolderName, DeveloperName FROM Report'
```

This is where I get the folder name and the name of the report.

Comment: Could be an issue with your `sfdx-project.json`. Can you retrieve other pieces of metadata using sfdx?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Report" object you can find the field "FolderName", but when querying to retrieve the report, you must use the folder developer name.
That's from the Folder object, so you need 3 steps:

1. select foldername , developername, ... from report where ...
2. select DeveloperName from Folder where name=' ...foldername from
   (1)...'
3. The you can do get the metadata with sfdx

sfdx force:source:retrieve -u orgAlias -m Report:Public_Reports/reportName

Note private reports are not available (you can vote on that on ideas.salesforce.com

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what the difference is between your suggestion and what OP has already tried.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, the error says: 
"ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project."
This means, that the directory where you want to run this command, is not your sfdx directory. 
Tip: you created a new project directory with

```
sfdx force:project:create --projectname XYZ ...
```

but after this command, you remain in the same dir where you started it, but it creates a subdir for the content with your project name. Entering into that dir you will be in a valid sfdx dir.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Public Report folder contains a space, so you need to place it in a quote like this:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u yourOrgAlias -m 'Report:Public Reports/yourReportName'
```

Also if you have the custom folder, and you need to retrieve that custom the Report Folder.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u yourOrgAlias -m Reportfolder:YourCustomReportFolder
```